# Why jwt.sign function doesn't recognize my user as object?

Tags: node.js, jwt, passport.js

I m working on project and I found weird problem, jwt.sign function doesn't recognize passed user as object, but when I make new object inside jwt.sign then it works fine.

If its hard to understand from text here is code:

```
var username = req.body.username;
var password = req.body.password;

User.getUserByUsername(username,(err, user)=>{
    if(err) 
        throw err;
    if(!user) 
        return res.json({success: false, msg: "User with username "+ username+" doesn't exist"});

    User.comparePassword(password, user.password, (err, passwordsMatched) =>{
        // Prints that user is type of object
        console.log("Type of user: "+typeof(user));
        if(err) throw err;

        if(passwordsMatched){
            // line bellow throws error that it expects object when I pass user
            var token = jwt.sign(user, Config.secret, {expiresIn: 604800});
            res.json({
                success: true, 
                token: 'JWT '+token, 
                user: {
                    name : user.name, 
                    username: user.username 
                }
            });
        }else{
            return res.json({success: false, msg: "Password doesn't match"});
        }
    });
});
```

Line `var token = jwt.sign(user, Config.secret, {expiresIn: 604800});` throws following error:

Error: Expected object
    at validate ...(Paths to jsonwebtoken and bcrypt modules + line where I call jwt.sign)

So I tried to fix and I found out that if I create new object out of user data inside function call then it works, it looks like this:

```
var token = jwt.sign({_id : user._id, 
                      username: user.username, 
                      password: user.password
                     }, 
                     Config.secret, 
                     {expiresIn: 604800});
```

So my question is why function doesn't accept my user objects and if there is solution to make it accept?

Comment: It seems that user is a mongoose object. Try doing `user.toObject();`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looking at the [code](https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken/blob/master/sign.js#L100) for `jsonwebtoken`, there is a call to lodash's [`isPlainObject`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#isPlainObject) function:

> Checks if value is a plain object, that is, an object created by the Object constructor or one with a [[Prototype]] of null.

Your `user` object must fail this validation check, which results in your error. Your attempted fix seems reasonable, but you can instead use [`toObject`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#toObject) if you're using Mongoose. e.g.:

```
var token = jwt.sign(user.toObject(), Config.secret, {expiresIn: 604800});
```